# I need to translate my htaccess for nginx to work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

well I have this mod_rewrite in my old apache configuration (htaccess) and I am trying to set up the configuration to nginx, but I can not really understand how it really works in nginx, I'm a newbie in all this nginx stuff, could anyone help me to translate this... Thank you so much in advance.

**Current htacces file:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/static/)

    RewriteRule . /app.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Virtual config file test.url:**

```
server {
    server_name test.url;
    access_log /var/www/test.url/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/test.url/logs/error.log;
    root /var/www/test.url/public_html/blank;

    location / {
        app.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/test.url/public_html/$
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
location / {
    app.php;
}
```

Try:

```
location /static/ {
    # do nothing, we don't want to rewrite /static/
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php
}
```

Comment: thank you! you made my day ;) i am starting to understand this.
Just one thing, you forgot ";" at the end of "try_files...